# How to import modified cells at the bottom of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I developed a macro that  imports a column from one sheet to another in the same Workbook. This works, but now what I want is that when I modify a cell in the first sheet, it doesn't crush it in the other sheet. Instead I would like it to add it to the bottom of the other sheet.

```
Public Sub Click()

 Sheets("PTR").Range("B6").Select
 lRow = Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Row
 Worksheets("Analyse").Range("C6:C" & lRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PTR").Range("B6:B" & lRow)
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you only want to copy the value or the whole cell with formatting

Comment: i wanna save the first one a add the modified one at the buttom

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have a problem understanding it. Still if you do, simply ask :)

```
Public Sub Click()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lRowWsI As Long, lRowWsO As Long

    '~~> Set your output sheet
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PTR")
    '~~> Find the last row where the data needs to go
    lRowWsO = wsO.Range("B" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> Set Input Sheet
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse")

    With wsI
        '~~> Find Last Row to get the range you want to copy
        lRowWsI = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Do the final Copy
        .Range("C6:C" & lRowWsI).Copy Destination:=wsO.Range("B" & lRowWsO)
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

To find the last row, you may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) post.

Comment: I tried ur solution ..but it did just reimport the old column not the modified one ..But  the problem is that i just want to import the modified cells not all of them

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong, if c10, c30 and c12 changed then you want to copy only those 3 cells?

Comment: exactly ..and i wanna add them at the buttom

Comment: In that case [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will get you started...